# Pandas - find rows with matching values in two columns and multiply value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

First suppose we have a dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'], 
                     'A':['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],  
                     'C':['10','10','10','30','50','60','50','8'], 
                     'D':['9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2']})
print(data)

    A   C   D   id
0   foo 10  9   1
1   bar 10  8   2
2   foo 10  7   3
3   bar 30  6   4
4   foo 50  5   5
5   bar 60  4   6
6   foo 50  3   7
7   foo 8   2   8
```

What I would like to do is find match rows and then do some calculation.

```
for any two ids(idx, idy) in data.iterrows():
       if idx.A == idy.A and idx.C = idy.C:
       result = idx.D * idy.D
```

and then generate a new dataframe with three columns `['id']`, `['A']` and `['result']`.

So a few rows of expected result is:

```
     id   A   result   
0    1   foo   63   
1    3   foo   63   
2    5   foo   15
3    7   foo   15
```

I have tried but the results are either wrong logic or wrong code/data format.
Can someone give me a hand please?

Comment: Does my answer work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to groupby A + C, take the product and count, filter out those that only have a single item in the group, then inner merge back on A + C to your original frame, eg:

```
df.merge(
    df.groupby(['A', 'C']).D.agg(['prod', 'count'])
    [lambda r: r['count'] > 1],
    left_on=['A', 'C'],
    right_index=True
)
```

Gives you:

```
     A   C  D  id  prod  count
0  foo  10  9   1    63      2
2  foo  10  7   3    63      2
4  foo  50  5   5    15      2
6  foo  50  3   7    15      2
```

Then drop/rename columns as appropriate.

Comment: I'm confused. Is OP asking for specific rows that filters number of rows in the group? I edited the question to `few rows of the output would be`, in his explanation of what he wants, he hasn't said that he hasn't added the part of the logic that would only return those rows where the count is 2.

Comment: Hmmm okay. I'm going by his logic.

Comment: Hello sir I have a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824046/pandas-find-and-iterate-rows-with-matching-values-in-multiple-columns-and-mult) relate to this one. Would you mind taking some time to check it out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use self-join technique:

```
data[['id', 'C', 'D']] = data[['id', 'C', 'D']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
joint = pd.merge(data, data, on=('A', 'C'))
joint = joint.loc[join['id_x'] != join['id_y']]
joint['result'] = joint['D_x'] * joint['D_y']
result = joint[['id_x', 'A', 'result']]
result.columns = ['id', 'A', 'result']
```

**Result**:

```
   id    A  result
1   1  foo      63
2   3  foo      63
7   5  foo      15
8   7  foo      15
```

Comment: better and faster `joint['result'] = joint['D_x'] * joint['D_y']` instead `joint['result'] = joint.apply(lambda x: x['D_x'] * x['D_y'], axis=1)`

Comment: Could also possibly make that: `joint = pd.merge(data, data, on=('A', 'C'))[lambda r: r.id_x != r.id_y]` but it's probably slower...

Comment: I got  'function' object is not subscriptable and fails to run

Comment: Sir your answer causes memory error when I tried on a large dataset. do you have any solution for it? @Lev Zakharov

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'id':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'], 
                     'A':['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],  
                     'C':['10','10','10','30','50','60','50','8'], 
                     'D':['9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2']})
```

First convert relevant columns to numeric

```
data[['C', 'D', 'id']] = data[['C', 'D', 'id']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Create empty DataFrame to append to

```
finalDataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
```

`groupby` two columns, and then find product of column `D` within group and append it.

```
group = data.groupby(['A', 'C'])
for x, y in group:


    product = (y[["D"]].product(axis=0).values[0])


    for row in y.index:
        y.at[row, 'D'] = product

    finalDataFrame = finalDataFrame.append(y, ignore_index=True)

output = finalDataFrame[['id', 'A', 'D']]
output = output.rename(columns = {'D': 'result'})
print(output)
```

gives you

```
   id    A  result
0   2  bar       8
1   4  bar       6
2   6  bar       4
3   8  foo       2
4   1  foo      63
5   3  foo      63
6   5  foo      15
7   7  foo      15
```