# How to access the current row data using column name in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to create a new column in a dataframe where I want to search the dataframe using the values in current row.
My columns are :

> Category, city,store, date, sales.

```
    Category        City            Store           OrderDate   Sales
0   Bakes & Cakes   New York        Bakesmith       2019-12-23  300
1   Bakes & Cakes   New York        Bakesmith       2020-01-18  500
2   Bakes & Cakes   New York        Cream Nd Cakes  2019-12-19  600
3   Bakes & Cakes   New York        Cream Nd Cakes  2020-01-12  400
4   Bakes & Cakes   London          Cream Nd Cakes  2019-12-31  1000
```

I want to do something like this:

```
df['Last month'] = df[(df['store']==df.current.store) & (df['city']==df.current.city) & (df['Category']==df.current.Category) & (df['date'] = some_date))
```

So basically I want to create a new column in a dataframe by slicing the same dataframe based on current row values.

How can I do this?

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: Sure we can help, before that you will need to provide sample input & expected output.

Comment: I can think of a few ways to do this.  It would be nice if you included a minimal example of the DataFrame in your question so we don't have to do the work for you. Please read [mre].

Comment: For example - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51808294/2823755) provided a copy-and-paste ready method to duplicate the DataFrame for their question. Sometimes `df.head(n)`  is sufficient but a statement that *makes* a DataFrame is really nice.

Comment: Hey @Sushanth. Sorry for not posting it earlier. I have updated my question with a sample datagram. Can you please check it now?

Comment: @wwii Sorry for not adding the dataframe earlier. I just edited and added the sample datagram. Can you please have a look at it now?